# Pass data from child state to parent state when leaving child state

Tags: javascript, angularjs, angular-ui-router

I've searched the web for ways to solve this problem and couldn't find best solution. Different approaches were involving using `data` on states, custom `services` or parent `$scopes`, but nothing seems to fit here.

I have parent controller with some object or variable and from this state I can go to child state in which I want to update the variable in parent and go back to parent. The code will explain it better.

```
function parentController($state) {
    var vm = this;
    vm.myVal = 1;
}

function childController($state) {
    var vm = this;

    vm.changeValue = function () {
        //TODO: change value of myVal in parent so it updates on view
        //if possible allow also updating or passing whole objects to parent
        return $state.go('parent');

        //is it possible to pass anything to reloaded state?
        //return $state.go('parent', {}, {reload:true})
    }
}
```

**Full working code is available [here on Plunker](http://plnkr.co/edit/EuKdtvGsLnnkLaXnMNYR?p=preview).**

I'm quite new to AngularJS so it's possible I get something fundamentally wrong and code needs reworking to allow this. I would rather stay with `controller as` syntax though.

What is the best way to approach this? Please fork the Plunker with working solution if you can.

Comment: As litteral solution to this post: http://plnkr.co/edit/1yhFAcGq7nUS37VtpAlr?p=preview. But i'm not sure if it's architecturally the best way of doing it. Moved "value" to "$state" oject. Controllers use same state instance.

Comment: Thanks! It works with `$state.go()`. Doesn't work with reload, but that's ok. Indeed binding view directly too `$state` looks weird but I don't know if this is bad practice. Anyway I need to do something first with this value in parent controller so I'd prefer if the controller updated the view somehow.

Comment: AFAIK it's not considered correct to have controllers 'talk directly to each other' but, you can get a hold of a controller by grabbing the element owning the controller with a JQuery selection and request the controller from it. I.e. $("div[data-ng-controller='ParentController']).controller();. Then you can call any method on the instance. You are just closely coupling the controllers in a logical sense.

Comment: But as you can see from the plunker my controllers are not set like this. So probably I can't get them this way. I can change my architecture to better one. I just need child controller to let know parent controller about what happened (it's for editing/adding elements to list which is displayed on parent view).

Comment: the Jquery selector is just an example. get the right element, call .controller() and you'll have the controller instance.

Comment: Revisit the http://plnkr.co/edit/1yhFAcGq7nUS37VtpAlr?p=preview for a 'signalling' approach.

Comment: Great! That's what I need. It works with changing state too. I'm pretty sure that `$scope` in your example is in fact `$state` as it is passed in controller definition, and because `$scope.go()` works well. Please add answer with your plunker code and link.

Comment: Ah, `$scope` has also `go()` method.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is an example of communication between 'parent/child' controllers by using the hierarchical behaviour of Angular's $scope. ($scope is special in angular!)

```
function parentController($scope) {
  var self = this;

  this.myVal = 1;
  this.myMessage = "Starting message";

  // set up method that child controllers can call.
  $scope.signalParent = function(data) {
    console.log("Parent signalled with " + JSON.stringify(data));
      self.myVal++;
      self.myMessage = data.msg;
      if (!$scope.$$phase) {
          $scope.$apply();
      }
  };
}

function childController($scope) {
  var self = this;
  this.changeValue = function() {
     // call the method from the parent.
    $scope.signalParent({msg: "Hello " + Math.random(100)});
  };
}
})();
```

Plunkr: [plnkr.co/edit/1yhFAcGq7nUS37VtpAlr?p=preview](http://plnkr.co/edit/1yhFAcGq7nUS37VtpAlr?p=preview)

The parent controller sets the $scope's "signalParent" property to be a function. Any lower level controller will 'inherit' the $scope and can therefore call the signalParent() method.

I must say that it is considered incorrect to communicate "directly between controllers" AFAIK. "event handling" & "signalling" is preferred.